# iPhone - respondToSelector returns NO but method is implemented

Tags: iphone, callback, response, selector

I have a class that declares and implements this :

```
- (void) callbackme:(OneClass*)p1 error:(NSString*)errStr {

}
```

and that calls in an instance method :

```
[self.obj oneAction:@"a string" sendAnswerToObject:self]; // obj is a custom class
```

in oneAction method of the custom class, I have :

```
- (void) oneAction:(NSString*)p1 sendAnswerToObject:(id)listener {

     if (listener != nil && ![listener respondsToSelector:@selector(callbackme::)]) 
             NSLog(@"Listener does not respond to selector 'callbackme:error:'");
}
```

The NSLog is triggered and I don't understand why ?

The listener must be an id as it can be any object instance of any class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your if should be

```
if (listener != nil && ![listener respondsToSelector:@selector(callbackme:error:)]
```

just as the log you created.